# prevblank() or startpara() function?

Tags: vim

For the purposes of fixing `indent/rst.vim` I would need a Viml function returning line number of the first line of paragraph (blank line separated set of lines). Does anybody have something like that written?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want `line("'{")`. It returns the number of (blank) line before the previous paragraph (or 1 if the paragraph is at the beginning of a file). See `:h '{` and `:h {`.

UPD. If we speak of a "complete" version:

```
function! StartPara()
    let l:lnum = line("'{")
    return l:lnum > 1 ? l:lnum + 1 : 1 + empty(getline(1))
    "or a shorter but a little more inefficient version:
    "return l:lnum + empty(getline(l:lnum))
endfunction
```

Note that a line containing only spaces is counted as a "paragraph" line, not as a "separator" line. Thus we don't need to match a regex.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve got even better answer on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/ecajyr/prevblank_or_startpara_function/fbaa49w?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x):

```
function! get_paragraph_start()
    let paragraph_mark_start = getpos("'{")[1]
    return getline(paragraph_mark_start) =~ '\S' ? paragraph_mark_start : paragraph_mark_start + 1
endfunction
```

which is kind of similar to what Matt suggested, but more complete.